# How to extend the GXT Theme Builder to generate a theme with appearances for my custom components?

Tags: gwt, extjs, themes, gxt

I have created a few custom components that come with their own appearance interfaces. Since now I want to use the Theme Builder to create our themes I also would like to have it generating the corresponding appearances for my custom interfaces.

Comment: Might be better posed as a feature request. Its technically possible (and we intend to make it easy), but without actually modifying and rebuilding the themer's original sources, you end up needing a ThemeBuilderBuilder to get it to generate all the right images...

Comment: Another idea would be to have the template outside the ThemeBuilder jar, so we could use our own template to do some tweaks. Now I was trying to add border-radius to a text field and by looking at the file Css3ValueBaseField.css I could see it is not prepared to accept it.

Comment: While that makes sense in theory, in practice we need to generate images, and this is achieved by actually running the gwt-compilable appearances in a headless browser (PhantomJS). If the template files are changed, then the JS app that is used to generate images has to be recompiled... and that means the themer takes longer and needs the whole GWT compiler built in (roughly doubling in size, adding another minute or two to the process). Hence, the ThemeBuilderBuilder concept.

Comment: Unless of course the world is ready to drop IE8/9, alas, not yet: http://theie8countdown.com/ and http://theie9countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

While we still don't have a ThemeBuilderBuilder, one possibility is to customize the CSS as explained in this other question:

[How to customize the CSS of a theme generated with the ThemeBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573085/how-to-customize-the-css-of-a-theme-generated-with-the-themebuilder/25573086)